# Trying to connect Azure SQL database from Azure ML Service using MSI authentication (Without username and passowrd connect the Azure database)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect the **Azure SQL Database** from **Azure Machine Learning Service** with **MSI Authentication (Without a username and password).**

I am trying to Machine learning model on azure Machine learning service that purpose I need data that' why I want to connect Azure SQL Database from Azure Machine Learning Service using MSI Authentication.

But I got below error:-

```
 "error": {"message": "Activity Failed:\n{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"code\": \"UserError\",\n        \"message\": \"User program failed with KeyError: 'MSI_ENDPOINT'\",\n
```

Please check the below code that I have used for the database connection.

```
import logging
import struct
import pyodbc
import os
import requests


class AzureDbConnect:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inside msi database")
        msi_endpoint = os.environ["MSI_ENDPOINT"]
        msi_secret = os.environ["MSI_SECRET"]

        resource_uri = 'https://database.windows.net/'

        logging.info(msi_endpoint)
        print(msi_endpoint)
        logging.info(msi_secret)
        print(msi_secret)
        print("Inside token")

        token_auth_uri = f"{msi_endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version=2017-09-01"
        head_msi = {'Secret': msi_secret}
        resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
        access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
        logging.info(access_token)
        print("Token is :- ")
        print(access_token)

        accesstoken = bytes(access_token, 'utf-8')
        exptoken = b""
        for i in accesstoken:
            exptoken += bytes({i})
            exptoken += bytes(1)
        tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

        conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                              "Server=tcp:<Server Name>"
                              "1433;Database=<Database Name>",
                              attrs_before={1256: bytearray(tokenstruct)})

        print(conn)

        self.sql_db = conn.cursor()
```

**Is there any way to connect Azure, SQL Database from Azure Machine Learning Service With MSI Authentication?**

Comment: the document says it should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-enterprise-security#securing-compute-targets-and-data.  but where did you get your sample code form ?

Comment: @Thomas I tried it but I got the above error.

Comment: did you activate managed identity ??? also it says it is not activatedby defautl on sql server

Comment: @Thomas Are you tried above code on azure ML Service?

Comment: @Thomas I am not able to see the Identity on Azure ML Service.

Comment: have you seen that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-enterprise-security#securing-compute-targets-and-data

Comment: @Thomas Yes but I am not able to understand how I can connect Azure SQL Database from Azure ML Service using MSI.  Do you have any example or code?  if you have then please share.

Answer (score 0):

Currently MSI Authentication is not supported to connect Azure SQL DB from Azure ML, It's on road map to add in future. You can Usually this is to do with setting up service principals in the DB, Attached is a step-by-step guide for getting this setup for Azure ML.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ram Actually above question is about the MSI on Azure ML Service

Comment: Currently MSI not supported on Azure ML service to connect Azure SQL DB.

Comment: @Ram Is there any documented part about the MSI not supported for Azure ML Service to connect Azure SQL DB? Please share the link if available.